# Can't make this message hook work in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to provide a `useMessage` hook for my components.

In my application, `Panel` is the largest component, the mother component, and it has a `Message` component in it that uses a Material UI's `Snackbar` to show messages and alerts.

Here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-tdd-d67v2i?file=/src/App.js)

Components use my hook this way:

```
import useMessage from './useMessage'

const SomeComponent = () => {
     const { success, error } = useMessage()

     return <button onClick={success('some message')}>Show success</button>
}
```

However, it does not change the `severity` and many times the message is empty. It does not work the way I expect it to work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

It seems the `useEffect` hook in the `useMessage` hook is the cause of all the trouble, specifically its interaction with the `hide` function.

```
const hide = () => {
  setIsMessageShown(false);
};
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (message && severity) {
    setIsMessageShown(true);
  }
  return () => {
    if (isMessageShown === false) {
      setMessage(null);
      setSeverity(null);
    }
  };
}, [
  message,
  setMessage,
  severity,
  setSeverity,
  isMessageShown,
  setIsMessageShown
]);
```

When `hide` is called it enqueues a state update to toggle the `isMessageShown` state false. `isMessageShown` is a dependency for the `useEffect` and there's a condition that checks if there's a truthy `message` and `severity` state. There is, since that wasn't cleared out too, so another state update is enqueued to toggle the `isMessageShown` state back true. At the same time, the `useEffect` hook is returning a cleanup function then enqueues state updates to clear the `message` and `severity` state, but the `Snackbar` and `Alert` components are still displayed.

There appears to be a state synchronicity issue from here on out and this is why the alert doesn't work the same after the first invocation.

## Solution

Commenting out, or removing, the `useEffect` hook appears to entirely resolve the issue you describe and reproduce in the codesandbox.

Here's an updated `useMessage` hook.

```
import { usePanel } from "./PanelContext";

const useMessage = () => {
  const { setIsMessageShown, setMessage, setSeverity } = usePanel();

  const show = (data, action, type) => {
    if (data && data.message) {
      data = data.message;
    }
    setMessage(data);
    setSeverity(type);
    setIsMessageShown(true);
  };

  const success = (data, action) => {
    show(data, action, "success");
  };

  const info = (data, action) => {
    show(data, action, "info");
  };

  const warning = (data, action) => {
    show(data, action, "warning");
  };

  const error = (data, action) => {
    show(data, action, "error");
  };

  const hide = () => {
    setIsMessageShown(false);
  };

  return {
    success,
    info,
    warning,
    error,
    show,
    hide
  };
};

export default useMessage;
```

I did a bit of refactoring to centralize the Panel context code & logic

PanelContext.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

export const PanelContext = React.createContext();

export const usePanel = () => useContext(PanelContext);

const PanelProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isMessageShown, setIsMessageShown] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  const [severity, setSeverity] = useState();

  return (
    <PanelContext.Provider
      value={{
        isMessageShown,
        setIsMessageShown,
        message,
        setMessage,
        severity,
        setSeverity
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </PanelContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default PanelProvider;
```

[image: Edit cant-make-this-message-hook-work-in-react]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. My concern is this. If for any reason `setMessage` and `setSeverity` take time, and they get applied after `setIsMessageShown`, then user sees the last message with the last severity and then in fron of his eyes the message changes and the color related to the severity changes. Is it a valid concern?

Comment: @HosseinFallah Sure, that's possibly a valid concern. You can always enqueue updates to clear/reset those states in the `hide` function if you like. I suspect any calls to `success`, `info`, etc... to show a new snack alert, it will, or should, set the message and severity state accordingly, so it might not be an issue at all.

Comment: But if I call `setMessage(null)` in the `hide` method, UX degrades. Because Alert first shrinks (no message to show) and then disappears. It's a bad UX. It's not smooth. That's why I tried desperately to clear `message` and `severity` in a `useEffect` hook's return value conditionally.

Comment: @HosseinFallah Yeah, I have seen that behavior before. It doesn't happen when not resetting those states, for example, like the codesandbox I shared. And like I explained, anything setting to display a new snack alert sets all the states accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => showSuccess()}>Success</button>
```

I think you should using an arrow function in render

Comment: Arrow function is for when you want to run code directly. It's for one liners. Basically your code and mine are the same. Thank you for the suggestion though.